# how to load spring_beans.xml based on spring profile

Tags: spring

I am trying to load the spring bean file based on a spring profile. 
so if the spring profile is FOO then I want to load foo_spring_bean.xml, and of the profile is BAR, then I want to load bar_spring_bean.xml

Is there a example I can look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked this blog post?

http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/

See "Enter bean definition profiles".